# How to generate Input-Data with Fuzzying for Coverage of disassembled 16bit/DOS game functions?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, reverse-engineering, fuzzing

so im doing reverse engineering of old 16bit real mode, segment/offset dos games (much harder then porting 32bit protected mode programs)

im always using IDA 7.x, Ghidra and some other tools to help my porting
the disassembler/decompiler of Ghidra is ok but miles aways from just copy&paste the result :), most other tools are even less capable or full of bugs, or not able to do 16bit code at all <-- i look at you HexRays!!!

for that i've extended dosbox to allow me hook complete functions or code-parts
so i can replace code and check if the game still runs with my ported version

i've also developed a super tiny/stupid "emulator" that have all the
needed assembler menomics as functions to be able to easily bring a disassembled function into dosbox
to run inside my VStudio IDE as normal but behave exactly the same as the original code
then i start to port that function step by step while testing if the game still works

my biggest problem is time and scale: for example some of the games i tackle have more then 800 functions
that is a huge workload and the super-easy ability to make bugs while porting from assembler to C/C++ weights much much
more then in a clean source based situation where source gets ported to a different higher-language (C to Java or something)

example routine (more or less simple compared to others):

```
void UNCOMPRESS_sub_1BAE7(emu_t &e)
{
start:
  e.push(e.es);
  e.push(e.di);
  e.cx = 0x80;
  e.ax = e.ds;
  e.es = e.ax;
  e.di = 0x301;
  e.xor (e.ax, e.ax);
  e.rep_stosw();
  e.pop(e.di);
  e.pop(e.es);
  e.sub(e.di, *e.word_ptr(e.cs, 0xBAA2));
  e.ax = e.di;
  e.shr(e.ax, 1);
  e.shr(e.ax, 1);
  e.shr(e.ax, 1);
  e.shr(e.ax, 1);
  e.cx = e.es;
  e.add(e.cx, e.ax);
  e.es = e.cx;
  ...
```

full source: https://pastebin.com/wPL4CUcV

the emulator is just +1MB memory, all registers (ax,al,ah,bx,cx,bp,ds,es,...) and some shr, push, xor, and, or functions
behaving the same (not in timing but in register, flag behavior) as the real ones

the big problem with that is: even when the game directly crashes if i did something stupid wrong
there are still many cases were it take some time + other ported functions with tiny bugs
to find errors in older ported functions - which is hard as you've got not real unit-tests to keep you safe

the other problem is: writing unit tests for >800 functions make the reversing even more
work intensive as the porting usually already is because due to the amount of functions and that i normaly
do not know what the function i want to port is doing at all

so my idea currently is (and i have no idea if that even can work)
to use something like KLEE or AFL/libFuzzer to create a bunch of happy-path "unit-tests" input-data for this code
to have something that my port can compete against and be always sure that the original code and my port behave the same
i know its not 1:1 or start the tool and thats it - im not doing reversing engineering because i think its easy :)

problems with that:

as the reversing base is always only global registers and global memory accesses there is no real
interface the fuzzer can work with, maybe i can express the registers as binary buffer, the memory itself is
already a binary buffer

the fuzzers are design primarily to find exceptions and errors - i just want to have as many happy-path inputs as possible
to have a good coverage of the code behavior

sub-functions that get called extend the test-data even more

so more or less register and memory states on start and register, memory state on end
so i can write (or better generate code like)

```
void test_func_ABC
{
  for(test-cases)
  {
     set registers, set memory based on fuzzy data
     run_original_routine

     set registers, set memory based on fuzzy data
     run_ported_routine

     compare results...
  }
}
```

so i don't need to start with that workload in every details on every functions - even
getting rid of 30% of the preperation workload would help alot

anyone here that can give me the lightest tips what could be help or what would be a good route to follow?

Comment: To do they jobs Klee and Afl try to cover all paths of the code, thus they can generate inputs covering many paths. I dont know how to run they on 16-bit code. Klee works on LLVM IR, you need something to transform 16-bit code to LLVM IR to use Klee.
Afl runs the code and measures the coverage for each input. Windows afl version winafl can measure coverage in 3 ways - the binary was compiled with coverage instrumentation, dynamic instrumentation with DynamoRIO or measuring using Intel CPU IntelPt feature.

Comment: Compilation with instrumentation requires source code, and you do not have it for the original game. I'm also not aware if there exist any way to compile a 16-bit binary with afl coverage instrumentation.
DynamoRIO does not support 16-bit code. I'm dont know if IntelPt supports 16-bit code and if yes, if winafl supports the structures that are created for 16-bit code.
Linux afl can use qemu user mode to run the binary and measure coverage, but I don't know if these tools can run 16-bit code.

Comment: im already reversing the 16bit asm code into 32/64bit asm-like-behaving code - so there is no 16bit code (it absolutely clear that todays tool can't handle 16bit code in any form)

Comment: You try to compare the original (run_original_routine) and the ported (run_ported_routine) versions of the code by running them. You have to run 16-bit code.